# Appamāda - What is it? How to practise it? Benefits?

Tags: personal-practice

In [this video](https://youtu.be/a-dpfv-G2Fs), Ven. Yuttadhammo Bhikkhu says that the whole of the Buddhist teachings could be summarized as Appamāda (heedfulness), at the risk of oversimplification.

In the [Mahaparinibbana Sutta (DN16)](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.5-6.than.html), the Buddha conveyed the last message of his life:

> Then the Blessed One addressed the monks, "Now, then, monks, I exhort
>   you: All fabrications are subject to decay. Bring about completion by
>   being **heedful**." Those were the Tathagata's last words.

According to the [Appamāda Sutta (SN3.17)](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn03/sn03.017.than.html):

> "There is one quality, great king, that keeps both kinds of benefit
>   secure — benefits in this life & benefits in lives to come."
>
> "But what, lord, is that one quality...?"
>
> "**Heedfulness**, great king. Just as the footprints of all living
>   beings with legs can be encompassed by the footprint of the elephant,
>   and the elephant's footprint is declared to be supreme among them in
>   terms of its great size; in the same way, **heedfulness** is the one
>   quality that keeps both kinds of benefit secure — benefits in this
>   life & benefits in lives to come."

Questions:

1. What really is Appamāda (heedfulness)?
2. How does one practise Appamāda (heedfulness)?
3. What are the benefits of Appamāda (heedfulness)?
4. Why is this one of the most important concepts in Buddhism, that the Buddha chose this to be his last message?
5. What is the relationship between Appamāda (heedfulness) and mindfulness? [This answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/1926/471) equates the two.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pamada is a condition of a happily misbehaving child or a drunken person enjoying oneself too much. A type of silly joyful carelessness that assumes no concern or responsibility for results of one's actions. There are many translations of this word - laxity, sloppiness, but the one I find particularly insightful is "indulging".

Appamada then is a sober, grownup, calculated attitude to things. A grownup may relax a little, but never loses sight of what results will the actions bring. Hence the usual translation, heedfulness, or my preferrence -  "sobriety".

One metaphor Buddhism uses a lot is that of intoxication. The three basic intoxicants of desire/obsession, negativity, and confusion/delusion cause the state of pamada, when one acts without proper regard for the consequences.

The practice of Appamada is certainly related to mindfulness, remaining aware and remembering the teaching at all times, but here the emphasis is on karma, or action and its expected result. Not only the physical action of course, but mental activity as well, including upadana, or fueling certain thoughts by giving them attention. We can either indulge in harmful thoughts uncontrollably, further fueling our intoxication, or be deliberate about our thinking, which leads to cessation of suffering. This last application of appamada can't be emphasized enough.

Appamada means always staying in planned, deliberate, results-oriented frame of reference, as opposed to merely acting out one's emotions and impulses. Every time before we think or say or do something, we ask ourselves, what will this achieve?

So that's one aspect, always being deliberate, and the other aspect is not letting oneself get intoxicated. We get intoxicated every time we get aroused by the scent of an external source of joy, or by a particularly inspiring form of negativity. We get excited off balance by the thought of either reward or righteous anger. If we let ourselves get emotionally intoxicated all the time, we practically never spend time being emotionally sober, which makes us mentally weak. Instead, staying sober and collected requires a certain kind of strength and will power. In a way, you always keep your spine straight, your feet on the ground, your eyes open, your mouth shut. That's appamada, sobriety.

Answer (score 4):

> **The whole of the Buddhist teachings could be summarized as Appamāda (heedfulness), at the risk of oversimplification.**

Sounds like oversimplication to me because *appamada* in itself can sound like it is a dhamma from the concentration faculty. For example, if I instruct a child: "*Be careful*", the child might reply: "*Be careful of what? What exactly do you want me to be watchful of?*"

Buddha-Dhamma is always lead by wisdom. Right view is the leader (MN 117). For appamāda to be of benefit, it must be co-joined with wisdom or must manifest from wisdom.

> **What really is Appamāda (heedfulness)?**

Without quoting any suttas, appamada is carefulness, namely, guarding the mind to avoid things that cause suffering or hinder development (*bhavana*).

> **How does one practise Appamāda (heedfulness)?**

Appamada cannot be practised without wisdom. 1st, one requires a data base of wisdom (right views). 2nd, one is vigilant, watchful or careful (*appamada*) to not transgress that wisdom data base.

Here, mindfulness (sati) is required. **Sati** is required to '**bring to mind**' whichever of those wisdoms is relevant to whatever situations.

Therefore, without quoting the suttas, I would guess appamada refers to the **preventative** aspect of sati-sampajjana (mindfulness & situational wisdom) that particularly engages in the 1st (preventative) effort of the noble eightfold path.

For example, there is the sutta about the dancing queen and the man walking with the pot of oil balanced on his head. Here, the man is instructed to practise heedfulness to avoid getting his head chopped-off by an executioner in the event he looks at the dancing queen. This sutta highlights 'appamada' as preventative (even though such prevention will naturally provide a foundation for the 'developmental').

> **What are the benefits of Appamāda (heedfulness)?**

Avoiding suffering (1st & 2nd Right Efforts of the noble path).

Provide a foundation for the 3rd and 4th developmental Right Efforts of the noble path.

> **Why is this (one of) the most important concepts in Buddhism, that the Buddha chose this to be his last message?**

It is a word that easily encapsulates or summarises the teachings, namely, be careful to avoid those things that cause suffering.

In fact, preventative heedfulness (appamada) is all that is really required for the *development* of samadhi, jhana & vipassana. In other words, the common intentional or positive 'yogic' efforts to focus on the breathing, etc, rarely work because all that is really required is the prevention of hindrances.

> **What is the relationship between Appamāda (heedfulness) and mindfulness? This answer equates the two.**

Mindfulness & appamada are not synonyms. The idea they are equated is wrong &
 sloppy (even though they are close). If they were synonyms, two different words would not exist. For example, I am sure suttas can be found that used both words in the same sentence. As I already explained, mindfulness is required to practise heedfulness.

For example, a mother says to a child: "*Be careful*". The child asks: "*Be careful of what?*". The mother replies: "*Since it is raining, be careful to not slip when you cross the road*". Therefore, when the child is crossing the road, in order to be heedful or careful, the child is always bringing to mind (using mindfulness) the wisdom of the mother: "*Mamma said the road is slippery, be careful; Mamma said the road is slippery, be careful*".

For heedfulness to manifest like the 'Elephant's Footprint' (as described somewhere in the suttas), many dhammas such as mindfulness, must be included ***within*** that Elephant's Footprint.

In short, *appamada* requires mindfulness & wisdom to make it manifest. There cannot be *appamada* without mindfulness & wisdom. Mindfulness is cause or subfactor of *appamada*, just as mindfulness is a cause or subfactor of concentration (*samadhi*).

In turn, appamada will be a foundation for higher development.

I found a sutta, which supports what I wrote, namely, appamada: (i) prevents the fermentations; (ii) leads to higher development; and (iii) is something different to mindfulness.

> *And what is **heedfulness**? There is the case where a monk guards his mind with regard to [mental] fermentations and mental qualities
>   accompanied by fermentations. When his mind is guarded with regard to
>   fermentations and mental qualities accompanied by fermentations, the
>   faculty of conviction goes to the culmination of its development. The
>   faculty of persistence... **mindfulness**... concentration... discernment
>   goes to the culmination of its development.*
>
> *Patitthita Sutta*

Answer (score 1):

Nyom Ruben,

There are good answers allready, by Nyom Andre and Dhammadathu.

My person guesses the greatest problem with all this and the reason why the Buddha pointed on it as his last gift, is that it is most serious. We might know all the good ways, yet we waste our time in talking and teaching others, or by endless asking, while we for ourself don't listen (doning the talk) and actually stay pamāda, conscienceless, unprincipled, unscrupulous (touse better and more urging translations), meaning, still causing us and others harm, rather to simply walk the way for benefit for all.

Nothing is solved and won by talking and dreaming.

Being conscienceless means to forget or deny the three Governing prinziples, the Self, the world, the Dhamma: [Adhipateyya Sutta: Governing Principles](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.040.than_en.html)

My person likes to add the story about one of Buddhas 
conscienceless disciple here:

> **[The Story of Thera Potthila](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.20.bpit_en.html#s-dhp-282)**
>
> While residing at the Jetavana monastery, the Buddha uttered Verse (282) of this book, with reference to Thera Potthila.
>
> Potthila was a senior bhikkhu who knew the Pitaka well and was actually teaching the Dhamma to five hundred bhikkhus. Because he knew the Pitaka, he was also very conceited. The Buddha knew his weakness and wanted him to mend his ways and put him on the right path. So, whenever Potthila came to pay obeisance, the Buddha would address him as 'Useless Potthila'. When Potthila heard these remarks, he pondered over those words of the Buddha and came to realize that the Buddha had made those unkind remarks because he, Potthila, had not made any serious effort to practise meditation and had not achieved any of the Maggas or even any level of mental absorption (jhana).
>
> Thus, without telling anyone Thera Potthila left for a monastery at a place twenty yojanas away from the Jetavana monastery. At that monastery there were thirty bhikkhus. First, he went to the most senior bhikkhu and humbly requested him to be his mentor; but the thera, wishing to humble him, asked him to go to the next senior bhikkhu, who in his turn sent him on to the next. In this way, he was sent from one to the other until he came to a seven year old arahat samanera. The young samanera accepted him as a pupil only after ascertaining that Potthila would obediently follow his instructions. As instructed by the samanera, Thera Potthila kept his mind firmly fixed on the true nature of the body; he was very ardent and vigilant in his meditation (*yoga: actually work the path, putting on self under the yoke,not just meditation, the whole path*).
>
> The Buddha saw Potthila in his vision and through supernormal power made Potthila feel his presence and encouraged him to be steadfast and ardent.
>
> Then the Buddha spoke in verse as follows:
>
> Verse 282: *Indeed, wisdom is born of meditation (yoga: work, doing); without meditation (yoga: actually work) wisdom is lost. Knowing this twofold path of gain and loss of wisdom, one should conduct oneself so that wisdom may increase.*
>   At the end of the discourse Potthila attained arahatship.

The Buddha didn't wanted his disciples, his followers, his heritage not to become a theater of actually worthless people - just think on the culter of the Brahmans he opposed, a folk of people who just talk and do not change things for them and the world for a better, and that is why his teachings and talks are actually contain more urging to be heedful than to explain the path, because the Dhamma it self is very simple and understood fast, simplier as our strategies to stay conscienceless.

At least my person leaves a wonderful talk by Bhante Thanissaro behind:

> **[The Practice in a Word](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/inaword_en.html)**, by Thanissaro Bhikkhu (1999; 3pp./8KB)
>   *Appamadena sampadetha!* — such was the dying Buddha's parting instruction, which has often been translated as "Practice diligently!" But a wider reading in the suttas reveals that that crucial word appamada has a far more nuanced and significant meaning. According to the author, the Buddha's real message was, "Don't be complacent. Watch out for danger. Protect the mind's good qualities. Don't let your guard down."

May it lead to conscience and having a sense of urgency!

How to keep urgency upright, practice that it stays on top? The Buddha gave all followers, monastics and lay people one reflection the should do: on death: Here the teachings of a merely unknown serious warrior: [Maraṇasati – recollection of death](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/thai/wanrut/exhortations_en.html#chap7)

Urging to conscience is the most compassionate act, at least because the urged often is not happy with it and some would agrue why one uges others. Because he/she knows that forgetting cause end effect or to do not know the effects of deeds lead to much suffering. Many also believe that the Buddha didn't urge unrequested, but he did, and also his monks had often compassion and went to householders and urged them. Here torward the Brahman Tigerprank:

> from [Dhanañjani Sutta: To Dhanañjani](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.097.than_en.html)
>
> On arrival, he exchanged courteous greetings with Ven. Sariputta and — after an exchange of friendly greetings & courtesies — sat to one side. As he was sitting there, Ven. Sariputta said to him, "I trust, Dhanañjani, that you are heedful?"
>
> "From where would we get any heedfulness, master? — when parents are to be supported, wife & children are to be supported, slaves & workers are to be supported, friend-&-companion duties are to be done for friends & companions, kinsmen-&-relative duties for kinsmen & relatives, guest duties for guests, departed-ancestor duties for departed ancestors, devata duties for devatas, king duties for the king, and this body also has to be refreshed & nourished."
>
> "What do you think Dhanañjani? There is the case where a certain person, for the sake of his mother & father, does what is unrighteous, does what is discordant. Then, because of his unrighteous, discordant behavior, hell-wardens drag him off to hell. Would he gain anything by saying, 'I did what is unrighteous, what is discordant, for the sake of my mother & father. Don't [throw] me into hell, hell-wardens!' Or would his mother & father gain anything for him by saying, 'He did what is unrighteous, what is discordant, for our sake. Don't [throw] him into hell, hell-wardens!'?"
>
> "No, master Sariputta. Even right while he was wailing, they'd cast him into hell."
>
> "What do you think Dhanañjani? There is the case where a certain person, for the sake of his wife & children ... his slaves & workers ... his friends & companions ... his kinsmen & relatives ... his guests ... his departed ancestors ... the devatas ... the king, does what is unrighteous, does what is discordant. Then, because of his unrighteous, discordant behavior, hell-wardens drag him off to hell. Would he gain anything by saying, 'I did what is unrighteous, what is discordant, for the sake of the king. Don't [throw] me into hell, hell-wardens!' Or would the king gain anything for him by saying, 'He did what is unrighteous, what is discordant, for our sake. Don't [throw] him into hell, hell-wardens!'?"
>
> "No, master Sariputta. Even right while he was wailing, they'd cast him into hell."
>
> "What do you think Dhanañjani? There is the case where a certain person, for the sake of refreshing & nourishing his body, does what is unrighteous, does what is discordant. Then, because of his unrighteous, discordant behavior, hell-wardens drag him off to hell. Would he gain anything by saying, 'I did what is unrighteous, what is discordant, for the sake of refreshing & nourishing my body. Don't [throw] me into hell, hell-wardens!' Or would others gain anything for him by saying, 'He did what is unrighteous, what is discordant, for the sake of refreshing & nourishing his body. Don't [throw] him into hell, hell-wardens!'?"
>
> "No, master Sariputta. Even right while he was wailing, they'd cast him into hell."
>
> "Now, what do you think, Dhanañjani? Which is the better: one who, for the sake of his mother & father, would do what is unrighteous, what is discordant; or one who, for the sake of his mother & father, would do what is righteous, what is concordant?
>
> "Master Sariputta, the one who, for the sake of his mother & father, would do what is unrighteous, what is discordant, is not the better one. The one who, for the sake of his mother & father, would do what is righteous, what is concordant would be the better one there. Righteous behavior, concordant behavior, is better than unrighteous behavior, discordant behavior.[2]
>
> "Dhanañjani, there are other activities — reasonable, righteous — by which one can support one's mother & father, and at the same time both not do evil and practice the practice of merit.
>
> "What do you think, Dhanañjani: Which is the better: one who, for the sake of his wife & children ... his slaves & workers ... his friends & companions ... his kinsmen & relatives ... his guests ... his departed ancestors ... the devatas ... the king ... refreshing & nourishing his body, would do what is unrighteous, what is discordant; or one who, for the sake of refreshing & nourishing his body, would do what is righteous, what is concordant?
>
> "Master Sariputta, the one who, for the sake of refreshing & nourishing his body, would do what is unrighteous, what is discordant, is not the better one. The one who, for the sake of refreshing & nourishing his body, would do what is righteous, what is concordant would be the better one there. Righteous behavior, concordant behavior, is better than unrighteous behavior, discordant behavior.[3]
>
> "Dhanañjani, there are other activities — reasonable, righteous — by which one can refresh & nourish one's body, and at the same time both not do evil and practice the practice of merit."

There is no reason for not and all reason for doing merits, but how far behind knowing that and teach that are you? Doing generous deeds, giving food, clothers, shelter, medicin at proper time? No. Keeping Silas serious? No. Make your duties? No. When teaching or learning, you do it for liberation? No, for gain.

But all that knowlegde, you might be able to cite all texts, what value does it have? Non, because it just like matterial wealth and you can lose it even in an hour, lates with death. You waste another live an at the end your merits, you goodeness are gone and nothing archived and no merits made.

All this learning has only one purpose, to gain enought faith to actually do the talk.

The is a reflection which is usally one of the first when becomming a monk, but good if one is able to reflect it, even if still a housholder, in Sri Lanka it is inkl. in the "House-bible" keep by lay followers usually, not called out of reason "[The Book of Protection](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/piyadassi/protection_en.html#ten):

> Discourse on the Ten Dhammas (Dasa-dhamma sutta [1])
>   Thus have I heard:
>
> On one occasion the Blessed One was living near Savatthi at Jetavana at the monastery of Anathapindika.
>
> Then the Blessed One addressed the monks, saying: "Monks." — "Venerable Sir," they said by way of reply. The Blessed One then spoke as follows:
>
> "These ten essentials (dhammas) must be reflected upon again and again by one who has gone forth (to live the holy life). What are these ten?
>
> 1. "'I am now changed into a different mode of life (from that of a layman).' This must be reflected upon again and again by one who has gone forth.
> 2. "'My life depends on others.' This must be reflected upon again and again by one who has gone forth.
> 3. "'I must now behave in a different manner.' This must be reflected upon again and again by one who has gone forth.
> 4. "'Does my mind upbraid me regarding the state of my virtue (sila)?' This must be reflected upon again and again by one who has gone forth.
> 5. "'Do my discerning fellow-monks having tested me, reproach me regarding the state of my virtue?' This must be reflected upon again and again by one who has gone forth.
> 6. "'There will be a parting (some day) from all those who are dear and loving to me. Death brings this separation to me.' This must be reflected upon again and again by one who has gone forth.
> 7. "'Of kamma[2] I am constituted. Kamma is my inheritance; kamma is the matrix; kamma is my kinsman; kamma is my refuge. Whatever kamma I perform, be it good or bad, to that I shall be heir.' This must be reflected upon again and again by one who has gone forth.
> 8. "'How do I spend my nights and days?' This must be reflected upon again and again by one who has gone forth.
> 9. "'Do I take delight in solitude?' This must be reflected upon again and again by one who has gone forth.
> 10. "'Have I gained superhuman faculties? Have I gained that higher wisdom so that when I am questioned (on this point) by fellow-monks at the last moment (when death is approaching) I will have no occasion to be depressed and downcast?' This must be reflected upon again and again by one who has gone forth.
>
> "These, monks, are the essentials that should be reflected again and again by one who has gone forth (to live the holy life)."
>
> So spoke the Blessed One. Those monks rejoiced at the words of the Blessed One.

And what is needed to be and stay conscience? Conscience. That is only archived by right View at first place, especialy the 1. Noble Truth and the backwards of all consciencelessness.

And how to put it into action? By being mindfull, remembering and keeping in mind and focus primarily on the frames of reference in all deeds, all times. Knowing the body, knowing the feelings, knowing the mind, knowing the phenomenas, all when arising, being present, decay. One who is mindful, one how practice mindfulness on the four frames of reference is a person that is conscience. Don't think that a person just siting in meditation is conscience. That is not for sure. But a person that does not seek after liberation, after archiving path and fruits, is a person of heedlessness, as well a person who does not know and ask for the way, askes people who have not archived anything aside knowing. Why?

> Cunda, it is impossible that one who is himself sunk in the mire[23] should pull out another who is sunk in the mire. But it is possible, Cunda, that one not sunk in the mire himself should pull out another who is sunk in the mire.

"It is not possible, Cunda, that one who is himself not restrained, not disciplined and not quenched [as to his passions],[24] should make others restrained and disciplined, should make them attain to the full quenching [of passions].[25] But it is possible, Cunda, that one who is himself restrained, disciplined and fully quenched [as to his passions] should make others restrained and disciplined, should make them attain to the full quenching [of passions]. Even so, Cunda...
>

> from [MN8](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.008.nypo_en.html)

And that's why you are lost without admirable friends, assosiating with fools or having just words and books. Because there is nobody watching you, taking benefical care and show you you heedless points, urge you to do good and blame you when tending to Mara and unbenefical. So if whe take heedfullness on the point where it starts is looking and assosiating with admirable friends the prerequisite to learn and do the whole path, to awakening. Don't be conscienceless and assosiate with friends in disguise just because they are similar or even more worth than you and your defilment (greed, aversion, notknowing, fear) rejoice with it, or you share the same preference of food and hobby together.

This talk would not find an end and to explain it was all the Buddhas and Noble Ones did since they really knew what they are talking about, so do it, the taught, at least out of gratitude in advanced so that you might say soon: "Awakened. The tasks is done, the heritage of the Buddha fullfilled, nothing further for this world."

**Appamadena sampadetha!** It's urgend also here! Learning is not even the half, but needs to be put in action and you can do it as well when learning, with mind, speech and body.

My Person spoke much about it ;-) mind it!

A maybe extended or edited answer can be found here  [[Q&A]Appamāda - What is it? How to practise it? Benefits?](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,8179.msg12958.html#msg12958) where you also be able to discuss the topic or answer in addition.

(*note: this is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpose or other wordily gains.*)

Answer (score 1):

### Definition of Appamāda&Mindfulness

Appamāda is sati, so appamāda is **"never forget the object of wholesome consciousness"**. Appa mean "no". Māda mean "forget" as alike as when someone drunk (pali: mada).

*Sāriputta* made summary, in kh.paṭi.,Abhidhamma and commentary, of **sati's definitions** from *various sutta* that sati has **apilāpana-mark** (always be aware of object of wholesome consciousness in mind), **asammoha-job** (never forget the object of wholesome consciousness), **ārakkha-appearance** (always keep object of wholesome consciousness in mind) and **thira saññā-closest cause** (strong and stable perception is the closest cause).

### To practice

See mahāsatipaṭṭhānasutta-pali, especially dhammānupassanāsatipaṭṭhāna, for more information (dhammānupassanāsatipaṭṭhāna appear in every pabba as samudaya-vaya-dhammānupassī).

### Benefits

See mahāsatipaṭṭhānasutta-pali's introduction and summary.

### The Last Message

Every sutta is 4 noble truths.  In the last night, **everyone around buddha saw buddha's physical suffering** (=saṅkhāra=khandha=decayed fabrications). So if they pamāda to hurry meditate, next life's body as alike as buddha's body infront of them, still go on and on (=paṭiccasamuppāda=loop).